# Writing CSV file in Clojure with writer

Tags: java, csv, clojure, server

I need to return from the server a CSV file.

I have the data which is a simple map, **I DO NOT want to create a file on the disk**, I saw that the write-csv function can accept as argument a writer.

Something like that (but it doesnt work):

```
(csv/write-csv (java.io.BufferedWriter. (java.io.OutputStream.  )) csv-data)
```

The error:

```
:cause java.io.OutputStream
 :via
 [{:type java.lang.InstantiationError
   :message java.io.OutputStream
```

Comment: "Does not work" is extremly broad.  What does not work?  Errors? etc.

Comment: `(java.io.OutputStream.  )` is an abstract class which can't be directly instantiated, so that's the cause of this specific error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. This is the my solution:

```
(let [writer (java.io.StringWriter.)]
    (csv/write-csv writer csv-data)
    (.toString writer))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a string, you could use `with-out-str`:

```
(with-out-str
  (csv/write-csv *out* csv-data))
```

Comment: it returns empty string.

Comment: What shape does your `csv-data` have?

Comment: `(with-out-str (csv/write-csv *out* [["foo" "bar"]]))` => `"foo,bar\n"`